# VB.NET error while adding a reference (.tlb)

Tags: .net, vb6-migration

I am Trying to add business object reference "busobj.tlb" to my project.
This tool was created in VB6 and recently we have started migration to VB.NET.

I tried adding the reference from project>Properties>References but it pops out a message saying "A reference to busobj.tlb could not be added,make sure that the file is accessible,and that is a validAssembly or a com component."

I am using Visual studio 2008 .Net framework 3.5.

Comment: Have you had a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx(v=VS.90).aspx ?

Comment: astander, you should add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These references are for .Net assemblies only.  Your vb6 .tlb won't work, at least via this mechanism.